# How to track down what's "melting" my laptop - spinning the fan

Tags: linux, google-chrome, cpu, fan, task-manager

### **Problem:**

CPU fan spins at random times.

### **Why it's a problem**?

Linux laptop is sitting in my room. Unused by me. Spins fan in irregular moments (probably using lot of CPU). Sometimes couple of seconds. Sometimes a few minutes. Then quiet again. A minute or few later fan noise again. The noise is very annoying. If I forget to turn laptop during night it wakes me up.

### **What I'm Asking?**

Please tell me how to track down what uses CPU and spins the fan.

Is there a tool which would record **in time what was using** lot of CPU? Ideally also **when** was fan spinning? I would like to let that tool running for a while and then look at the data collected and find the root cause (or multiple).

### **What I already know?**

I know tools like `top` or `htop` for linux processes. If I'm staring at them I can *kind of guess* what could be the reason, but it's difficult and could be incorrect guess. When Chrome browser is likely to blame, I need to go to `Chrome Task Manager` (tree dots menu->More Tools->Task Manager), the same problem. I need to stare for long and guess what could be the issue.

*E.g. If the process is really Chrome, and there is one stupid tab which needs to use all my CPU for whatever reason I can just make sure I close it when not needed. Or I can stop using that site, but I need to find out which webapp (chrome tab) it is. If it's not a chrome, but another linux process, I will know if it's legitimate use or if I can close it. Alternatively reduce priority or somehow else convince the process not to use all the resources at random times.*

Comment: Does it only happen when chrome is running?

Comment: I haven't tested that. Chrome is running basically nonstop on my laptop.

A tracking just for Chrome specifically would be useful. Ideally I would like to know how to track linux processes too. If for nothing else then just to confirm it's always Chrome. Chrome is also AFAIK running a thread for each tab, so tracking at OS level could perhaps do the trick too.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221555/retrieve-cpu-usage-and-memory-usage-of-a-single-process-on-linux) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659460/get-ram-and-cpu-usage-for-process-in-linux-with-c)?

Comment: Use your linux System monitor it shows usage graphs

Comment: What version of Linux are you running, and which kernel? I think these two bits of information can assist.

Comment: I'd be asking why is your laptop fan so noisy?  Fans only make Eddy Current noise from turbulent velocity against a fixed surface.  Raising away from the table by 1cm might reduce the noise or avoiding suffocating the air intake for convection cooling.  Ensuring the display is asleep and other basic power consumers is where I would start.

Comment: @Andrej I recently wrote [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1584656/257269) about Chrome 100% CPU using... you may find it interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `pidstat` from `sysstat` package to avoid scripting and parsing `top`

You can either target a specific process with `-C`, you can also monitor children by a specific process with `-T CHILD`

Say you want to know what happens when you sleep. You can make it run while you sleep for ~8 hours

`pidstat 75 384 --human > usagelog`

This command would run every 75 seconds 384 times, thats 28800 seconds the equivalent of 8 hours. If it happens within less time, you can do 1/3 of 75 and multiply 384 by 3, that would give you a report every 25 seconds.

This would at least give you clear insight over night, which background processes spike CPU. `pidstat` will also give you a nice average at the completion of your command:

```sh
Average:      UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest   %wait    %CPU   CPU  Command
Average:     1000      1345    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.02     -  wslbridge2-back
Average:     1000      6266    0.02    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.10     -  pidstat
Average:     1000      6269    0.08    0.04    0.00    0.00    0.12     -  zsh
Average:     1000      6275    0.04    0.06    0.00    0.02    0.10     -  wslbridge2-back
Average:     1000      6278    0.18    0.08    0.00    0.00    0.26     -  zsh
Average:     1000      6305    0.64    0.26    0.00    0.02    0.90     -  vim
Average:     1000      6310    1.54    0.54    0.00    0.02    2.08     -  node
```

As you can see, my main CPU offender when running only vim in shell is node from `coc.nvim`

Answer (score 1):

### Fan speed and temperature

With the command `sensors`, `sudo apt install lm-sensors`<sup>[[1](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-fan-speed-in-linux-for-cpu-and-gpu/)]</sup>, you can check the temperatures of the various devices (motherboard, CPU as a whole, single cores, graphics card etc) .

With the additional graphic program `psensor` (`sudo apt install psensor`), as well as the equivalent ones, you will have a GUI with the plot of the desired temperatures.

It is enough to spot when the temperature rises too much, in case even before the fans start to spin.  In many cases **sensors** also gives you the value of the **fan rotation speed**.

#### A Script

You already know the `top` command. With `man top` you have access to the explanation of the various options that allow you to sort the output as you like, in this case by seeing the cpu usage.

If you add the `sleep`, `sort`, `grep` (maybe `head`, `tail` and `awk`) commands you have pretty much all the tools you need to build a script and find the program that has extreme demands when the temperature (or the fan speed) rises.

### Some hardware and software causes

**Software.** The sudden increase in computer activity during the night, or without an apparent reason, can be caused by some updates or some scheduled tasks at certain times (or in some cases at times with low loads): system updates, re-indexing of databases such as that of files (and their content if active)...
**Check for *cron* and *anacron* scheduled actions.**

**Browser specific.** For chrome/firefox/chromium pages loaded and perhaps running a damaged or unresponsive script, you can try reloading the page.
In another answer [[2](https://superuser.com/a/1584656/257269)], there are several tips/add-ons that can help limit the browser's impact on system requests.

**Hardware** There are also some non-software-dependent reasons that cause the temperature to rise and the computer's fans to start. For example if the **vents are blocked** by dust accumulated over time, or by a pillow, blanket or other fabric, or simply the computer is not raised enough to circulate the air pumped by the fans.
*All over again*: the fans may end up heating even more the computer which pauses the processors (`dmesg` to control it), accumulating processes that are later run together when the processor is switched on again, causing a peak of requests which heats the processors again and then restart the fans...

#### Additional note on the fan speed regulation

In general, the temperatures at which the computer fans start can be controlled at the operating system level [[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed),[4](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control)] or even directly from the motherboard.
Be curious and check the settings of your motherboard: you may find threshold temperatures above which the fan starts spinning at different speeds. There are usually also operating modes: from *quiet* with the fans off when not needed, to *performing* when they are almost always on. It is motherboard dependent.